# I would like to inquire about the issue with Mac terminals. zprofile: 1: command not found: 'eval'

Tags: terminal, mac

Sorry, my English is not very good, so all of these are translated from websites

Whenever I turn on the terminal, the following text will appear

Thank you for your assistance

```
/Users/tomo/.zprofile:1: command not found: ‘eval
/Users/tomo/.zprofile:1: command not found: ’
/Users/tomo/.zprofile:2: command not found: ‘eval
/Users/tomo/.zprofile:2: command not found: ’
/Users/tomo/.zprofile:3: command not found: ‘eval
/Users/tomo/.zprofile:3: command not found: ’
/Users/tomo/.zprofile:4: command not found: ‘eval
/Users/tomo/.zprofile:4: command not found: ’
➜  ~ head ~/.zprofile
‘eval export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew"; export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar"; export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew"; export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}"; export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:"; export INFOPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";’ eval export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew"; export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar"; export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew"; export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}"; export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:"; export INFOPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";
‘eval export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew"; export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar"; export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew"; export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}"; export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:"; export INFOPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";’ eval export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew"; export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar"; export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew"; export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}"; export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:"; export INFOPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";
‘eval export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew"; export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar"; export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew"; export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}"; export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:"; export INFOPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";’ eval export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew"; export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar"; export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew"; export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}"; export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:"; export INFOPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";
‘eval export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew"; export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar"; export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew"; export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}"; export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:"; export INFOPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";’ eval export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew"; export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar"; export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew"; export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}"; export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:"; export INFOPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";

eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
➜  ~
```

Comment: There's no good reason to use `eval` for any of these lines except the brew shellenv one, btw, and there are lots of good reasons _not_ to use `eval` without good reason. `export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew" HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/cellar" HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew" PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"` works perfectly fine without any `eval`, without the undesired/unnecessary/inappropriate single quotes, and without repeating `export` once for each variable (and if one only runs `export` once, then all the `;`s can go away too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.zprofile` looks a bit messed up.

- Run `nano ~/.zprofile`
- Delete the four identical lines, do *not* change the last one
- Save the file and exit (see bottom line for relevant key shortcuts, `^` is the <kbd>Control</kbd> key)

Then open a new Terminal tab to verify that it works.

Comment: Hello, I followed your instructions to operate the terminal and it is now working properly. Thank you very much